# How do I use schema crawler to establish a connection with the database and get the result?

Tags: scala, db2, schemacrawler

I'm using this Gradle dependency in my project

```
implementation group: 'us.fatehi', name: 'schemacrawler', version: '16.16.14'
```

The project is in `Scala` language and `DB2` is the database that's used.

This is piece if scala code I'm using:

```
val limitOptionsBuilder = LimitOptionsBuilder.builder
           .includeSchemas(new RegularExpressionInclusionRule("schema_name"))
           .includeTables((tableName: String) => !tableName.contains("table_name_thats_in_the_above_scema"))

val loadOptionsBuilder = LoadOptionsBuilder.builder.withSchemaInfoLevel(SchemaInfoLevelBuilder.standard())

val options = SchemaCrawlerOptionsBuilder.newSchemaCrawlerOptions
                  .withLimitOptions(limitOptionsBuilder.toOptions())
                  .withLoadOptions(loadOptionsBuilder.toOptions())


var catalog :Catalog = null
catalog = SchemaCrawlerUtility.getCatalog(connection, options)
```

I'm getting this below exception:

```
SchemaCrawler database plugin should be on the CLASSPATH for <my_db2_classpath>,
or "SC_WITHOUT_DATABASE_PLUGIN" should be set to the name of the missing plugin
either as an environmental variable or as a Java system property
```

Is there any other setup that I need to do before using Schemacrawler to connect to the database?
Ideally, I need to connect to the database and get the relations between the tables in the form of ER diagram in HTML/PDF format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add a dependency on

[group: 'us.fatehi', name: 'schemacrawler-db2', version: '16.16.14'](https://search.maven.org/artifact/us.fatehi/schemacrawler-db2/16.16.14/jar)

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](https://www.schemacrawler.com/)

Comment: Thanks for this it worked, but it gets stuck when .getCatalog method is called.
Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @wagonr - when you say "stuck" you mean it takes a lot of time to obtain the catalog? Can you temporarily try by restricting "includeTables" to just one table? What happens if you use a minimum "withSchemaInfoLevel"?

Comment: Yeah, it takes a lot of time to get the Catalog. I've added only 1 table name in 'includeTables'. Even with the minimum 'withSchemaInfoLevel' it takes a lot of time.

Comment: Hi @sualeh-fatehi, I had to get the relationship between the tables in that schema, by generating ER diagram in either PDF/Text format, How do I do that? I tried giving the tables' name in .includeTables method, but it didn't work. Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: This discussion has moved beyond the question. Please put your discussions on https://github.com/schemacrawler/SchemaCrawler/discussions